# DocuSign Template GET Rate Limits

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on integrating DocuSign into our service, and one of the things I want to do is GET the details of a Template. I noticed in the documentation (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits#api-rules-and-limits) that Envelope endpoints are limited to one GET per endpoint per fifteen minutes. I wanted to know if this limitation applies to Templates as well. Or any of the non-Envelope endpoints, for that matter.

Some examples of endpoints I'm interested in:

- https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/get
- https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Connect/ConnectConfigurations/get

Answer (score 0):

This limitation is about approving your app to go live. It is not a technical limitation. You can make such API calls. The reason is that we don't want your app to use polling as means to check status. Since you're using a template and not an envelope it's less likely you're doing polling and so your app should be approved.